# Scientific to decimal notation

Tags: tables, siunitx

I get numbers in scientific and decimal notation from a script (R-script).
How can I force the numbers into either decimal or scientific notation in a table? (Possibly with siunitx?)

My current status:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
        \sisetup{round-mode=places
        ,round-precision=3
        ,scientific-notation=false
    }
    \caption{Train} 
    \begin{tabular}{lrr}
        \toprule
        Naming & Number 1 & Number 2\\
        \midrule
        Group 1     & \num{4.569975e-05}    & \num{0.0003580374}    \\
        Group 2     & \num{8.919496e-06}    & \num{0.0090821639}    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]
But in this case I want both numbers in decimals, three digits (Yes I know that there will be zero)
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the options `scientific-notation=fixed` and `fixed-exponent=0` to `siunitx`. (See also pp. 25f. of the package's user guide.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\sisetup{round-mode=places
        ,round-precision=3
        ,scientific-notation=fixed,
        fixed-exponent=0}
\caption{Train} 
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
Naming & Number 1 & Number 2\\
\midrule
Group 1     & \num{4.569975e-05}    & \num{0.0003580374}    \\
Group 2     & \num{8.919496e-06}    & \num{0.0090821639}    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```